# Something Wrong with our Stats on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed

Our [stats seem to be off on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947/project-management). See questions asked per day and number of avid users.

[image]

Comment: Good find! It seems to be happening for other sites too.

Comment: You can track this on [the main Stack Exchange meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234383/who-borked-the-area-51-stats) and [Area 51 meta](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/16914/area-51-stats-down).

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is solved now... the only "problem" to solve now would be the questions per day rate. :P

BTW, for the ones interested in our stats... here they are: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10947?phase=beta&users=mostactive#tab-top

Comment: I think it may be time to revisit the question of "when will we go out of beta?"